About Lord Shiva in sleeping position
In have seen Lord Shiva in Sayana position sometimes, in fact there was a temple of Lord Shiva called Palli Kondeswara Temple. It's interesting and also i wanted to ask it for some days.
So, my question is, Did any scriptures mention Lord Shiva's sleeping position?

The story of Bhagawan Palli Kondeswara, it goes something like this.:

During the Samudra manthan (churning of the ocean of milk) by the gods and demons, many treasures along with the Amrita (elixir of the gods) and the poison Halahala rose from the ocean. To rescue the beings of the world from the poison, Shiva consumed it. When the poison was just going down the throat of Shiva, his consort Parvati stopped it there by tightly holding Shiva’s throat, turning Shiva's neck blue. After the episode, Shiva proceeded to his abode Kailash with Parvati. On the way, he felt exhausted and slightly uncomfortable, when he reached a place in the bounds of Andhra, which came to be called Suruttappalli. There, he lay down to relax, keeping his head in the lap of Parvati. The gods, who were concerned about Shiva's well-being, assembled there and stood around him, waiting for the Lord to open his eyes. This lying posture of Shiva is rare and unique, almost similar to Vishnu’s reclining posture.


Might be present in some Sthala Purana.
As for scriptural reference of Bhagawan Shiva in sleeping position.:
Mahabharata 13:17:96.:

“ūrdhvaretā jale śayaḥ |”
“Thou (Rudra) art the one, who floats on the waters after the universal dissolution”.

I hope this helps. Prd..
